# How many frequencies can a laser emit (aside from doubling)?

Tags: laser

This article - ["Chip can transmit all of the internet's traffic every second"](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2342833-chip-can-transmit-all-of-the-internets-traffic-every-second/) makes two related claims:

- > The chip needs a single laser, shining continuously, which is split into many frequencies, as well as separate devices to encode data into each of the output streams.
- > Next, each of these channels was split into 223 data chunks that existed in individual slices of the electromagnetic spectrum. This “frequency comb” of equidistant spikes of light across the spectrum allowed data to be transmitted in different colours at the same time without interfering with each other, massively increasing the capacity of each core.

So this surprises me: I thought lasers were monochromatic, in fact, that was a key feature.  And then of course there is frequency doubling (and higher multiples).

But I didn't realize you could get an "equidistant" "comb" of as many as 233 different frequencies out of a single laser.

How is that done?

Comment: Monochromatic light doesn't exist, since it corresponds to an infinitely extending sine wave. All light has some frequency distribution, given by the Fourier transform of the EM-wave. In practice, the frequency bandwidth of lasers is limited by the bandwidth of the laser medium and the optical components.

Comment: ufff. Search for mode-locked lasers. That's where you should start. The laser they used (a dark solitonic micro-ring resonator) is just too complex to explain here. But for a better idea, search for mode-locked lasers. Your assumptions that lasers are monochromatic is extremely basic and far far far from reality....as physics nobel prizes of 2005, 2018 and chemistry 1999.